# Product of Unit Quaternions Converging As a Series

Tags: functional-analysis, summation, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quaternions

I'd like to start posting some of the questions I muse about on here to find out the thoughts of others and give other enthusiasts problems which are hopefully fun and nontrivial. My objective is to include some "hard" (to me) "open" (as far as I know) questions to counterbalance the many homework/project/reference questions we already get. Here is my first:

Recall that an arbitrary unit quaternion can be represented by $e^{p}$ where $p$ is a pure quaternion. Let $\{p_n\}_n$ be a sequence of pure quaternions and suppose further that $\sum_{n}^\infty p_n$ converges to $p$. Does it follow that $\prod_n^\infty e^{p_n}$ converges? Is there a (possibly trivial) $f$ such that it converges to $e^{f(p)}$?

If the word "quaternion" is dirty to you, you are free to replace it with "element of $SU(2)$".

**Edit:**
The case of $q_n$ being a constant sequence is easy, has $f(p) = p$, and the convergence is "if and only if".

Comment: I see no reason to normalize the $p_n$s. You can generalize your question: Suppose $G$ is a connected Lie group with lie algebra $\frak g$. Then does the following hold? $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n \,{\rm~ converges~in~} {\frak g} ~\iff~ \prod_{n=1}^\infty \exp(X_n)\, {\rm ~converges~in~} G.$$ (Convergence in $\frak g$ is independent of inner product.) Note if $G$ is nonabelian, there cannot be an $f$ such that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \exp(X_n)=f\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right)$, since the product can be changed without altering the value of the sum.

Comment: The normalization comes from the application this stems from: If I represent the attitude of a spacecraft using the quaternions, when does the sequence of attitude commands from a discrete controller converge? In this case $a_n$ would be the principle angle of the $n$th iterate and $q_n$ its invariant axis. I see your point though and will edit the question.

Comment: Since the quaternion product is non-commutative, how exactly do you want $\prod_{k=1}^n q_k$ be defined? Obvious choices are $q_1*q_2*\dots*q_n$ or $q_n*\dots*q_2*q_1$, but even $q_1*q_n*q_2*q_{n-1}*\dots$ could be possible.

Comment: @Wauzl the product is as you would expect it to be. $\prod_n^\infty e^{p_n} = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\prod_n^N e^{p_n}$ and $\prod_n^N e^{p_n}= e^{p_N}e^{p_{N-1}}\cdots e^{p_2}e^{p_1}$.