# Ideals of Modular Lipschitz Quaternions II: Progress and New Questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules, quaternions

I recently asked a [queston](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249901/proper-nontrivial-ideals-of-modular-lipshitz-quaternions) regarding the proper, nontrivial ideals of what I called the modular Lipschitz quaternions, which was part of my series of open problems for enthusiasts. As luck would have it, I realized only after the fact that my key assertion--the quaternion ring $Q_p$, where $p$ is prime, is a field if it is a domain--is wrong. The specific issue is the inapplicability of Wedderburn's theorem, since it is easy to show every quaternion ring of characteristic $>2$, even over a general coefficient ring $R$, is noncommutative (thus cannot possibly be a field!). Thus the work done by @rschwieb and @MatheiBoulomenos shows that none of the $Q_n$ are domains (which, as @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez pointed out, is actually a simple consequence of Wedderburn's little theorem in each case but $Q_2$) but, due entirely to my error, failed to answer the original question. In order not to edit all meaning out of the previous post, I have decide to create this post as a new home for the questions. To wit, these are

1. For which $n$, if any, does $Q_n$ have at least one proper nontrivial ideal?
2. If $Q_n$ has proper nontrivial ideals what are their orders? How, if at all, are they related to the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

As remarked by @rschwieb, it is obvious that an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ generates an ideal of $Q_n$. The converse does *not* hold (at least for general $n$), as @JyrkiLahtonen has identified a proper, nontrivial ideal of $Q_2$.

Although an initial attempt at a proof by myself was not successful (as pointed out by @JyrkiLahtonen, whose comments are of interest even taken on their own), it yielded two lemmas which may or may not be helpful. We use the following notation: if $A$ is a set of quaternions $P_1A$ is the set of coordinates of 1 contained in $A$, $P_iA$ the set of coordinates for $i$, and so on. We will call these the unit projections of $A$.

**Lemma 1.** *If $S$ is an additive subgroup of $Q_n$ then the unit projections of $S$ are (possibly different) additive subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n.$*

Computing the unit projections of $q-p$, for $q,p\in S$ shows this immediately.

**Lemma 2.** *If $I$ is an ideal of $Q_n$, then the unit projections of $I$ are the same subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.*

*Proof:* If $I$ is an ideal it is, in particular, an additive subgroup of $Q_n$. Lemma 1 implies the unit projections of $I$ are additive subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. To show these groups are the same, we need only show they contain the same members. For instance, suppose $a \in P_1I$. It follows that there is a quaternion $q \in I$ for which $P_1q = a$. Since $I$ is an ideal, it is closed under multiplication by the elements of $Q[n]$, in particular $i$, thus $iq \in I$ and therefore $a \in P_iI$. On the other hand, if $a \in P_iI$ then multiplication by $-i$ shows $a \in P_1I$. The other equalities are established in a similar way.

**New Questions**

Finally, I leave the community with two new questions related to this topic.

3. Classify the ideals of $Q[R]$, where $R$ is an arbitrary ring. Particularly, we may suppose $R$ is finite.
4. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion) partially documents work on the Hurwitz and Lipschitz quaternions. One question I find particularly compelling is whether or not a similar theory of irreducible factorization can be created for $Q_n$ or $Q[R]$.

Comment: Something I couldn't follow: How did you conclude that $I=Q(P_1I)$? Assuming that was how the main claim was supposed to follow from Lemma 2. Compare to $R=\Bbb{Z}_5[i]$. Lemma 1 and Lemma 2 seem to go thru with that commutative ring. Yet $R$ has a non-trivial ideal generated by $(2+i)$. Observe that the corresponding ideal $I$ of $Q_5$ generated by $(2+i)$ is the whole thing. But this needs the fact that $j(2+i)j^{-1}=2-i$. Implying that $(2+i)+(2-i)=4=-1\in I$. You need something like that to conclude.

Comment: Actually I'm fairly sure that $1+i+j+k$ generates a non-trivial ideal of $Q_2$. Of course, $Q_2$ is a special case because it happens to be commutative.

Comment: Here's a teaser. It is known that the Brauer group of a finite field is trivial (follows immediately from Wedderburn). So if you can show that $Q_p$ has no non-trivial ideals for some $p>2$, then $Q_p$ is central simple over $\Bbb{F}_p$. Therefore $Q_p$ must be isomorphic to the ring of $2\times2$ matrices over $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My thinking was that Lemma 2 implies $P_1I = P_iI = P_jI = P_kI$ I think I see the issue though, which is the equivalence of the projections doesn't guarantee that all possible combinations of coefficients are found in the ideal.

Comment: Indeed, that is the problem.

Comment: I would like to get a "clean" version of this problem and think a third follow-on would be a bit much. I will edit this latter, but I wanted to thank @JyrkiLahtonen for his remarks. Do you mind if I send you an email sometime, Jyrki?

Comment: I guess that what happens is that with a prime $p>2$ you have [a generalized quaternion algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra). That is known to be central simple, and therefore isomorphic to that matrix algebra. I don't know if I can contribute more. If something else occurs to me, I will reply.